# Unable to assign a value to the first element of an empty vector

Tags: julia

### Goal

I want to initialize an empty vector `vn_ff` and then update it with a `for loop`. Before running the loop, I assign the first element by myself but I get an error.

### Code

```
# Constants
time_length = 5
n = 1

vn_first = Vector([4.42]) # could be multiple values if n > 1

# Initialize an empty vector of size time_length
vn_ff = Vector{Float64}()
sizehint!(vn_ff, time_length)

## Provide the first value of vn_ff by myself
vn_ff[1] = vn_first[n]

ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 0-element Vector{Float64} at index [1]
Stacktrace:
 [1] setindex!(A::Vector{Float64}, x::Float64, i1::Int64)
   @ Base .\array.jl:903
 [2] top-level scope
   @ Untitled-1:12

# for loop will be used to update vn_ff
```

How do I initialize `vn_ff` so that I can assign the first element and then later assign remaining elements in the `for loop`?

Comment: There is no point in writing `Vector([4.42])`, that just takes a vector and converts it to a vector (which it already was). You just write `[4.42]`. In this respect, Julia is less like numpy and more like Matlab, arrays are native to the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's not the right way to do this, you want

```
vn_ff = Vector{Float64}(undef, time_length)
```

Comment: Could you please explain why the `sizehint!` approach is wrong?

Comment: `sizehint!` is just a 'hint', it doesn't change the size of the vector, but allocates memory in the background to make e.g. `push!` more efficient.

Comment: to resize a vector use `resize!` instead of `sizehint!`.

Comment: @DNF and Bogumil Kaminski Thank you.